# Windows CMD Illuminate\Database\QueryException - Could not find driver

Tags: php, laravel

Tried to run `php artisan migrate` in Windows Command Line, but it shows this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\htdocs\demophp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:742
    738▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error    739▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a   
    740▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.     
    741▕         catch (Exception $e) {   ➜ 742▕             throw new QueryException(
    744▕             );
    745▕         }
    746▕     }

  1   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\htdocs\demophp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\htdocs\demophp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connect PDO::__construct()
```

And my extensions in `php.ini`:

```
;extension=odbc
;extension=openssl
;extension=pdo_firebird
extension=pdo_mysql
;extension=pdo_oci
;extension=pdo_odbc
;extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pdo_sqlite
;extension=pgsql
;extension=shmop
```

What can be the problem and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to comment out the following in your php.ini file For Windows.

```
;extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

For Linux :

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysql
```

Don't Forget To Restart